# Custom Post Type fields not working when moved to online server

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been developing a Wordpress theme that makes use of Custom Post Types and CMB Plugin. All was working fine on the my local server (MAMP), but when I moved it all to my live server I started to get the following error when I accessed the pages for my **Events** and **Venues**...

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in`...`on line 6`

Line 6 begins the following code:

```
$event = [
    'title'     => the_title('','',false),
    'id'        => get_the_ID(),
    'support'   => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_supporting_bands', true ),
    'datetime'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_datetime', true ),
    'desc'      => wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_event_desc', true ) ),
    'image'     => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_event_image', true ),
    'hlcolor'   => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_highlight_color', true ),
    'age'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_event_agelim', true ),
    'tixavail'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_tickets_avail', true ),
    'doorprice' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_ticket_price_dp', true ),
    'advprice'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_ticket_price_ps', true ),
    'ticketurl' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_tix_url', true ),
    'ticketloc' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_ticket_loc', true ),
    'shorturl'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_short_url', true ),
    'artistbio' => wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_bio', true ) ),
    'artistfb'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_fb_url', true ),
    'artisttw'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_tw_url', true ),
    'artistweb' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_web_url', true ),
];
```

I've been racking my head all night trying to figure this out. I've re-uploaded the site, checked all my code for conflicting variables and other things, and I still can't figure it out. I even changed the database back to my localhost and tried it out... works fine on the localhost. Changing it back to the live server makes it not work. The rest of the site works fine too.

What could be happening? Is this a PHP issue? My localhost uses PHP 5.4.10, my live server uses PHP 5.3.27...

Thoughts?

Comment: Please review how to get values here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood php array syntax.

Also remove comma from last item

Syntax should be `$event = array( items1, item2, item3 );` see all items separated by a comma(`,`). so no need a comma after last item.

Use it as:

```
$event = array(

     'title'     => the_title('','',false),

     //.........

     //rest of items

     //.........

     'artistweb' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_web_url', true )// remove comma from this line
);
```

Comment: For `PHP` array, it doesn't matter whether the last `comma` exists or not.

Comment: You win because you posted it first! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4.x has [new feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) to declare array like you did in `localhost`. In PHP 5.3.x or in all version, the following will work.

```
$event = array(
    'title'     => the_title('','',false),
    'id'        => get_the_ID(),
    'support'   => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_supporting_bands', true ),
    'datetime'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_datetime', true ),
    'desc'      => wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_event_desc', true ) ),
    'image'     => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_event_image', true ),
    'hlcolor'   => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_highlight_color', true ),
    'age'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_event_agelim', true ),
    'tixavail'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_tickets_avail', true ),
    'doorprice' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_ticket_price_dp', true ),
    'advprice'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_ticket_price_ps', true ),
    'ticketurl' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_tix_url', true ),
    'ticketloc' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_ticket_loc', true ),
    'shorturl'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_short_url', true ),
    'artistbio' => wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_bio', true ) ),
    'artistfb'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_fb_url', true ),
    'artisttw'  => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_tw_url', true ),
    'artistweb' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ecmb_artist_web_url', true ),
);
```